# Manipulate form components by form's name

Tags: forms, delphi, ado

I have a Form class that I use to generate multiple form objects from. And I rename each generated form.

I don't know how to acces the specified form components without affecting the other generated forms components.

I have used this code but always the components of the last created form are affected:

```
procedure TmainForm.OFBloqueButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (mainForm.tabSheetBool = True) AND (mainForm.OFID <> '') then begin
       if OF_bloque = False then begin
           Application.CreateForm(TOFOperationsForm, OFOperationsForm);
           OFOperationsForm.Caption := 'Bloquer OF';
           OFOperationsForm.Name := 'OFBloqueForm';
           OF_bloque := True;
       end;
       OFOperationsForm.BringToFront;
       OFOperationsForm.ADOOF.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM OFTab WHERE ID=''' + OFID + '''';
       OFOperationsForm.ADOOF.Open;
    end;
end;
```

My objective is to manupulate the specified ADOQuery of the wished form.

Thank you.

Comment: Setting the Name property of the new form is not necessary, if your code later does not depend on it, and so could be removed from the code example here too.

Comment: I named the form to call it by its name.

Comment: Does the 'flag' OF_bloque mean there will be at most one form?

Comment: TLama I guess the OF_bloque will prevent the creation of a second form. Not sure though.

Comment: The question title is "Manipulate form components by form's name" - where / how does your code use the form name? This is not shown.

Comment: @mjn, aha, you're right. I've missed that; I'm not familiar with `begin` on the end of the code line.

Comment: yes, OF_bloque is to prevent the creation of the same form.

Comment: You wrote "My objective is to manupulate the specified ADOQuery of the wished form." - but if there is only one form instance, you can always access it through OFOperationsForm.ADOOF. To access it from various places, I would make OFOperationsForm a (private) field of the main form class.

Comment: I have another methods that acces the ADOQuery that I dont mentioned here because the code it too long.

Comment: The other methods do use FindComponent (using the form name), instead of the form variable? Sorry, but the question does not provide enough information about the main problem.

Answer (score 4):

When you create multiple instances of a form class then you should not use the variable declared by the IDE in the form's unit. In fact, most Delphi developers I know delete that var as soon as they create a new form, only an app's mainform retains it because the dpr wants it.

Also, you don't need to go finding the form using FindWindow or even iterating over the Application's or Screen's forms. Just use a local var when you create it:

```
procedure TmainForm.OFBloqueButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  NewForm: TOFOperationsForm;
begin
    NewForm := nil;
    if (mainForm.tabSheetBool = True) AND (mainForm.OFID <> '') then begin
       if OF_bloque = False then begin
           NewForm := TOFOperationsForm.Create(Application);
           NewForm.Caption := 'Bloquer OF';
           NewForm.Name := 'OFBloqueForm';  //<== You'll need to make this unique!
           OF_bloque := True;
       end;
       if Assigned(NewForm) then begin
         NewForm.BringToFront;
         NewForm.ADOOF.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM OFTab WHERE ID=''' + OFID + '''';
         NewForm.ADOOF.Open;
       end;
    end;
end;
```

**Edit**

Added some safety's to the above code to prevent AV's. As it stands it means that the Query is not changed unless a form is created. If it is the intention to set the query of a new form or to change the query of the last form created, then you need a member field in TmainForm:

```
TmainForm = class(TForm)
private
  FLastFormCreated: TOFOperationsForm;
//...
```

and change the code in the ButtonClick handler to:

```
procedure TmainForm.OFBloqueButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (mainForm.tabSheetBool = True) AND (mainForm.OFID <> '') then begin
       if OF_bloque = False then begin
           FLastFormCreated := TOFOperationsForm.Create(Application);
           FLastFormCreated.Caption := 'Bloquer OF';
           FLastFormCreated.Name := 'OFBloqueForm';
           OF_bloque := True;
       end;
       if Assigned(FLastFormCreated) then begin
         FLastFormCreated.BringToFront;
         FLastFormCreated.ADOOF.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM OFTab WHERE ID=''' + OFID + '''';
         FLastFormCreated.ADOOF.Open;
       end;
    end;
end;
```

I have left in the Assigned check, because without the rest of the code I cannot judge whether it would logically be possible to arrive at the `BringToFront` without FLastFormCreated having received a reference at least once (ie in case OF_Blogue is set to True elsewhere).

Comment: OF_bloque is a flag meant to indicate 'there is a form already, do not create another one'

Comment: "My objective is to manupulate the specified ADOQuery of the wished form." - this requires to make the variable accessible from other methods

Comment: +1 "most Delphi developers I know delete that var as soon as they create a new form..."

Comment: but I got ACCESS VIOLATION ERROR.

Comment: Yes, well I didn't bugproof your code, just showed you how to use a local reference to a form. You are creating the form conditionally, so you need to skip `NewForm.BringToFront` or make sure NewForm references an existing form before calling that. To use Assigned(NewForm) NewForm should also be intialized to nil, as local variables are not initialized by default.

Comment: `NewForm` is local to this routine. Thus `OF_bloque` is superfluous, and causes OP's AV when True. Make `NewForm` a member of TMainForm or of its unit.

Comment: @NGLN: Yes, when OF_bloque is True the AV occurs but that is to be expected. Making NewForm a member of TMainForm just adds another form variable with only a slightly less global scope than the one in the OFOperationsForm unit. It would merely disguise the AV as it would use the last form created. Now if that is what OP wants, fine but name it `LastFormCreated` or some such. I certainly would not make it a var in the mainform's unit, as that really is hardly any better than the form var in the OFOperationsForm itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that you create multiple forms that erase the pointers to the previous forms, and you end up with a pointer to the lastly created form.

You could iterate Screen.Forms to obtain a reference to the desired form, here's an example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  NewForm: TForm2;
begin
  // create two forms, then show the first form
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, NewForm);
  NewForm.Name := 'FirstForm';
  NewForm.Caption := 'This form was created 1st';
  Application.CreateForm(TForm2, NewForm);
  NewForm.Name := 'SecondForm';
  NewForm.Caption := 'This form was created 2nd';
  // iterate Screen.Forms to access the first form by name
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
    if Screen.Forms[i].Name = 'FirstForm' then
      Screen.Forms[i].Show;  // shows the first form
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
unit main;

interface

uses
    Windows, Messages, ... , OF_operations;

type
    TmainForm = class(TForm)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    private 
    ...
    public
         OFBloqueForm, OFCancelForm, OFDelaisClientForm, OFInspectionForm: TOFOperationsForm;
    end;

// Bloquer OF
procedure TmainForm.OFBloqueButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if (mainForm.tabSheetBool = True) AND (mainForm.OFID <> '') then begin
        if OF_bloque = False then begin
            OFBloqueForm := TOFOperationsForm.Create(Application);
            OFBloqueForm.Caption := 'Bloquer OF';
            OFBloqueForm.Name := 'OFBloqueForm';
            OF_bloque := True;
        end;
        OFBloqueForm.BringToFront;
        OFBloqueForm.ADOOF.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM OFTab WHERE ID=''' + OFID + '''';
        OFBloqueForm.ADOOF.Open;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: what was the problem - did simply changing the referenced units solve it?